# What to do with many L1 resonators?

Tags: ingress

I have many L1 resonators but can't deploy them anywhere because all portals are full. Can I upgrade them with XM or something similar? Even if I hack any portal I mostly only get L1 resonators although I am already at L3

Comment: If you're getting L1 res as an L3, the portal is low level - try to farm L3 or higher level portals

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't need them, give it to your faction L1 players, so that they can deploy them and therefore level up.

L1 resonators are perfect to booby trap the portal, as it will get destroyed very fast especially if put close to the strongest resonator, the owner of the resonator will get notified once it is destroyed and can counter attack - recharge the portal remotely.

Comment: Good tip about putting the L1 resonator near the strongest resonator so it'll go early for a warning.  If I'm able to, I also try to put the strongest resonator somewhere difficult to get to, like in a building, then leave a level 1 resonator somewhere accessible like on a sidewalk.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Just recycle them. They are so useless and easy to get that you could better use the XM gotten by recycling  them than bothering on dropping them so your friends could pick them up. They will be in your same situation of too many of those.</strike>

The other alternative is always deploy them first then upgrade them. If you have the time at an unclaimed portal you could deploy 8 L1 and the start upgrading to L2 and keep going up to your max of 1 L8, 1 L7, 2 L6, 2 L5, and 2 L4.

If you do this correctly you could deploy up to 45 resonators on a single portal instead of just 8 and get faster your Builder medal.

<sub>1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1

3   3   3   3   2   2   2   2

4   4   4   4   3   3   3   3

5   5   4   4   4   4   3   3

6   6   5   5   4   4   4   4

7   6   6   5   5   4   4   4

8   7   6   6   5   5   4   4</sub>